# In Visual Studio 2019, is there a way to turn off promotional messages such as "Got a minute? Tell us how to improve the Azure SDK! Take the survey"

Tags: visual-studio

Periodically, Visual Studio displays a message:

> Got a minute? Tell us how to improve the Azure SDK! Take the survey

It is bright yellow and it disturbs my workflow.

I would love to know if and where the setting is to turn off this nuisance.

Comment: Can you show exactly where and when does those spam messages appear?

Comment: while I feel for the sentiment in the question here, this doesn't seem to be programming related, or something that this site should be taking sides in.  If you are using a company's product to develop on their platform, then why would they not have a right to ask you questions about your experiences with that process?  That's hardly spam.....

Comment: "*Periodically, Visual Studio displays a message*" It would help to add a screenshot and some details of your setup/workloads/extensions/etc for the benefit of those who are not seeing such messages.

Comment: Guessing you already checked your VS Code settings? Some extensions have settings to ask you surveys, and you can turn it off through the VS Code settings. I have no idea about the Azure SDK, though.

Comment: What if you start the survey and don't complete it?

Comment: Switch to VIM text editor.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do is that -  ***Next time whenever you get that message, check on the "Don't show this message again".***
The second option is that - you should take the survey. If you take that survey, there are chances the message myight not show up again

Answer (score -2):

The notifications can be due to Re-sharper version.

Can you check which version you are using, I have heard they had a glitch and many users were having issue the same as yours.

Below image can help on how to disable.

Open the main settings, and changing all of them to "Ignore":

[image]